# Unable to Connect to Apache Spark Kafka Streaming Using SSL on EMR Notebooks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to connect to a Kafka consumer secured by SSL using spark structured streaming but I am having issues. I have the Kafka consumer working and reading events using `confluent_kafka` with the following code:

```
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'url:port',
        'group.id': 'group1',
        'enable.auto.commit': False,
        'security.protocol': 'SSL',
        'ssl.key.location': 'file1.key',
        'ssl.ca.location': 'file2.pem',
        'ssl.certificate.location': 'file3.cert',
        'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'
        }


consumer = Consumer(conf)


consumer.subscribe(['my_topic'])

# Reads events without issues
msg = consumer.poll(timeout=0)
```

I'm having issues replicating this code with Spark Structured Streaming on EMR Notebooks.

This is the current setup I have on EMR Notebooks:

```
%%configure -f 
{
  "conf": {
    "spark.jars.packages": "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.3.0",
    "livy.rsc.server.connect.timeout":"600s",
    "spark.pyspark.python": "python3",
    "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.enabled": "true",
    "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.type":"native",
    "spark.pyspark.virtualenv.bin.path":"/usr/bin/virtualenv"
  }
    
}
```

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark import SparkFiles
```

```
cert_file = 'file3.cert'
pem_file = 'file2.pem'
key_file = 'file3.key'

sc.addFile(f's3://.../{cert_file}')
sc.addFile(f's3://.../{pem_file}')
sc.addFile(f's3://.../{key_file}')
```

```
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()
```

```
kafka_df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "url:port") \
    .option("kafka.group.id", "group1") \
    .option("enable.auto.commit", "False") \
    .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
    .option("kafka.ssl.key.location", SparkFiles.get(key_file)) \ # SparkFiles.get() works 
    .option("kafka.ssl.ca.location", SparkFiles.get(pem_file)) \
    .option("kafka.ssl.certificate.location", SparkFiles.get(cert_file)) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .option("subscribe", "my_topic") \
    .load()
```

```
query = kafka_df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)") \
    .writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .start()
```

And no rows appear in the Structured Streaming tab in the spark UI even though I expect the rows to show up instantly since I am using the `earliest` `startingOffsets`.

My hypothesis is that readStream doesn't work because the SSL information is not set up correctly. I've looked and haven't found `.option()` parameters that directly correspond to the `confluent_kafka` API.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _haven't found .option() parameters that directly correspond to the confluent_kafka API_ - Because there isn't. Spark uses JVM Kafka library, not Python/librdkafka... See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs , then Spark needs `kafka.` prefix on those properties

Comment: @OneCricketeer I do have `kafka.` parameters there. What do you mean?

Comment: What about enable auto commit (which Spark doesn't accept anyway). My point was that you need to look at the Java properties, but you said you were looking at Confluent/Python props, none of which are valid for Spark